# problems about setting pgrouting with QGIS under windows

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I followed this website：[A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) and now facing some problems.

I finished steps before "Creating a routable road network", and open QGIS 1.8, click the PostGIS Manager plugin, here's the figure：[image], the first question is that how to enable PostGIS support？

And if I click the Data button trying to load data from shapefile, here's the figure：[image]

And when I try either way：back to QGIS menu->click the Database->shp to postgis->key in my password->click connect, then it shows：[image]

How to solve these problem and correctly use pgrouting？

ps.I work under windows7 64-bit, and have QGIS1.8, postgres8.4, pgadmin3, postgis2.0 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed PostGIS but everything seems like the database you are using for the pgrouting exercise is not PostGIS-enabled. After installing PostGIS on Windows, there should be a postgis_template database. Did you create your pgRouting database using the postgis_template?

Comment: I create an new database based on template_postgis_20，and load 3 sql files again, then I open QGIS, click PostGIS Manager, how can I set link to the new database instead of directly linking to the older one：template_postgis_20？

Comment: After read your comment I open pgadmin3 and create an new database based on template_postgis_20, named routing_template, but when I go to QGIS, I still got the same problem like the first photo in my questions.

Comment: Did you connect to routing_template using Add PostGIS Layer - New?

Comment: I Add PostGIS Layer, and it works(I add a polygon file), but when I try either way：use PostGIS Manager, I still got the second photo in my question. When I want to add a polyline file in pgadmin as you described in your pgrouting tutoral, I got this message：Importing with configuration: tochienrouting, public, geom, C:\Users\HeinzChen\Desktop\new _folder\ToChienRouting, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Arc
PostGIS type: MULTILINESTRING[2]
Error reading shape object 15

Shapefile import failed.